# Insert into a table with a select from another table + my own data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, `table1` and `table2` in MySql

**table1**

```
"id"    "name"  "description"   "path"  "type"  "country"
```

**table2**

```
"id"    "type"  "country"
"2"     "5"     "US"
"3"     "10"    "US"
"1"     "1"     "US"
```

I'm trying to insert data into `table1` from `table2`, along with data that comes from a form.

So this is kind of what I'm trying to do, but I don't think its correct. Can you please help? Name, Description and Path come from a form.

```
insert into table1 (id,type,country,name,description,path) 
values 
( (select id,type,country from table2 where id = 1),'My Name,'MyDescription','My Path')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper syntax is:

```
Insert into table1 (id,type,country,name,description,path) 
    select id, type, country, 'My Name', 'MyDescription', 'My Path'
    from table2
    where id = 1;
```

The `values` and `select` syntax do not mix.  To be honest, I never use `values` because `select` does everything it does, and more.